# In clojure, how can I undef a var from a namespace?

Tags: namespaces, clojure, interactive, slime

In clojure I have lines like this that define default values:

```
(def *http-port* 8080)
```

I've now decided to formalize these kinds of values into a configuration unit and I would like to undefine the value `*http-port*` so that I can find the locations that still refer to this value and change them to use the new value. I'm doing a refactoring in other words by moving the value to a different location.

The way I've been doing this is to quit slime and try to restart the slime session. During maven's compile phase errors like these are picked up and I can find and fix one reference at a time. I then fix the error, wash rinse and repeat. This is obviously frustrating.

How would I do this while connected to a slime session?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, [`ns-unmap`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ns-unmap) should do what you want:

```
user=> foo
java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: foo in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
user=> (def foo 1)
#'user/foo
user=> foo
1
user=> (ns-unmap (find-ns 'user) 'foo)
nil
user=> foo
java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: foo in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
```

Comment: Other namespaces may still hold references to the value of 'foo.

Comment: @Jurgen this is true, but the solution is better than nothing

Comment: Just to remember: the default namespace is 'clojure.core